# Skip a specific number of rows while pulling data from another worksheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am pulling data from another worksheet in the same file, and I would like the formula to skip 3 rows instead of 1 row, as I drag the formula through the column.

For example, Worksheet1!A10=Worksheet2!A10, Worksheet1!A11=Worksheet2!A13, Worksheet1!A12=Worksheet2!A15, Worksheet1!A13=Worksheet2!A16

Is this possible to do in Google Sheets?

I tried linking the first few rows manually and then dragging the formula, hoping Google Sheets will understand the relationship, but it doesn't.

Comment: Your example does not make sense to me. You want the results in Worksheet1!A10:A13 to be Worksheet2!A10 ... A13... A15... A16. The interval there is 3 then 2 then 1, not "skip 3 rows." It is best if you share a link to a sample spreadsheet with some data in Worksheet1 and Worksheet2, being sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone > Editor."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign formula every 16th row on sheet "Report" to reference other sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/149469/assign-formula-every-16th-row-on-sheet-report-to-reference-other-sheet)

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Here's a link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lYKNPlls7lA2pAHdBs9-jayfN-P3kpU2yl2avAh3s1Y/edit?usp=sharing



Desired Result=>
Worksheet 1!I6=Worksheet2!B5
Worksheet 1!I7=Worksheet2!B12
Worksheet 1!I8=Worksheet2!B9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you don't necessarily need to drag anything, but rather that you want every value from Column B of 'Worksheet 2' where Column A = "FII." Assuming that is correct, I added a sheet ("Erik Help") with this formula in I6:

```
=FILTER('Worksheet 2'!B:B,'Worksheet 2'!A:A="FII")
```

Comment: This is great, it worked, Thanks a lot for taking the time, Happy New Year to you and your loved ones.

Comment: Happy to help, Ess. And Happy New Year to you and yours as well.